# django queryset ..search objects from one field of a model to another field of the other model

Tags: django-queryset

I have to build a queryset in which we can select all the objects from a field in a model and compare to the field in another model...

For Eg:- i have to select all the objects in docid field  with corresponding amount from profitandloss model and compare to docid with corresponding amount from balancesheet model

Model -1

```
 Class Profitandloss(models.Model):
      docid = models.charfield(max_length=15)
      amount = models.integerfield(default=0)

 class balancesheet(models.Model):
      docid = models.charfield(max_length=15)
      amount = models.integerfield(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model design needs changing. you should have `document` as another model and link document model to your `profileandloss` and `balancesheet` model as `foriegnkey` This will allow ORM search effectively